# Add reseting index to spark dataframe

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark

I have a dataframe I would like to add an index column to reset based on one of the columns

```
--------------------
|  ColA   |  ColB  |
====================
|  G1     |  10    |
--------------------
|  G1     |  20    |
--------------------
|  G2     |  50    |
--------------------
|  G2     |  10    |
--------------------
|  G2     |  70    |
--------------------
```

I would like the result to be

```
-----------------------------
|  ColA   |  ColB  |  ColC  |
=============================
|  G1     |  10    |   1    |
-----------------------------
|  G1     |  20    |   2    |
-----------------------------
|  G2     |  50    |   1    |   <== reset because ColA changed
-----------------------------
|  G2     |  10    |   2    |
-----------------------------
|  G2     |  70    |   3    |
-----------------------------
```

Is there anything like 
df.withColumn("id", monotonicallyIncreasingId) 
that would be appropriate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Window` to make partitions for the column `colA`.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window

val w = Window.partitionBy("ColA").orderBy("ColB")
df.withCloumn("id", row_number.over(w))
```

Or, if you want to keep the original order of rows,

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window

val w = Window.partitionBy("ColA").orderBy("temp")
df.withColumn("temp", monotonically_increasing_id)
  .withCloumn("id", row_number.over(w))
  .drop("temp")
```